# Combine multiple json to single json using jq

Tags: jq

I am new to jq and stuck with this problem for a while. Any help is appreciable.

I have two json files,

In file1.json:

```
{
    "version": 4,
    "group1": [
        {
            "name":"olditem1",
            "content": "old content"
        }
    ],
    "group2": [
        {
            "name":"olditem2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And in file2.json:

```
{
    "group1": [
        {
            "name" : "newitem1"
        },
        {
            "name":"olditem1",
            "content": "new content"
        }
    ],
    "group2": [
        {
            "name" : "newitem2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected result is:

```
{
    "version": 4,
    "group1": [
        {
            "name":"olditem1",
            "content": "old content"
        },
        {
            "name" : "newitem1"
        }
    ],
    "group2": [
        {
            "name":"olditem2"
        },
        {
            "name" : "newitem2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Criterial for merge:

1. Has to merge only group1 and group2
2. Match only by name

I have tried

```
jq -S '.group1+=.group1|.group1|unique_by(.name)' file1.json file2.json
```

but this is filtering group1 and all other info are lost.

Comment: On a match, should the elements in `file1.json` be updated (i.e. overwritten) by those from `file2.json`, or is it the other was round? Merging algorithms tend to follow the former ordering, but your expected output suggests the latter. (From the items in `.group1` with name `olditem1`, the expected output features the one from `file1.json`, not the one from `file2.json`.)

Comment: Yes, file1 objects should take precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach uses `INDEX` to create a dictionary of unique elements based on their `.name` field, `reduce` to iterate over the group fields to be considered, and an initial state created by combining the slurped (`-s`) input files using `add` after removing the group fileds to be processed separately using `del`.

```sh
jq -s '
  [ "group1", "group2" ] as $gs | . as $in | reduce $gs[] as $g (
    map(del(.[$gs[]])) | add; .[$g] = [INDEX($in[][$g][]; .name)[]]
  )
' file1.json file2.json
```

```json
{
  "version": 4,
  "group1": [
    {
      "name": "olditem1",
      "content": "new content"
    },
    {
      "name": "newitem1"
    }
  ],
  "group2": [
    {
      "name": "olditem2"
    },
    {
      "name": "newitem2"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eZIlkf7nUI)